# what is the definition of Section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Giving a surjective morphism $\phi : S \rightarrow C$ from e complex algebraic projective surface to a projective curve i've found the term section of the morphism $\phi$ but i don't have some references. What is the definition?

Answer (score 3):

A section is a morphism $\psi : C \to S$ such that $\phi \circ \psi : C \to C$ is the identity.